# How to hide a group of columns and show them when a header column is clicked?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and have already divided the top into two columns. I need to re-create the design in the sample image without using JavaScript or jQuery. So that when I click "Quick Info", a new set of columns (containing Quick Info) appears.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: absolutely no idea what the question is whatsoever :/

Comment: What do you mean link?  Are you just trying to work out the position of a div?

Comment: Put the code you are using now

Comment: To make separator, you can use CSS border property. Either use border-left on 2nd col-md-6 or border-right on first col-md-6. Second, to link the top, you can use <a href="#{ID}">Back to top</a> where ID can be any ID on the top of page like #nav for navigation container or #content for content container

Comment: Look at the sample image, you'll get the idea

Comment: @e-ba'e We don't understand your sentences in the question, so the sample image doesn't really help. What do you mean by "link the top and the info right under"? What top? What info? Link in what way?

Comment: @TylerH forgive me, I'm new here. In the sample image, there is "mark the date" (which is active). Because it is active the date is clearly shown under. To the right, there is "quick info" which on click brings up something else. I was just wondering how to make that design using only css and html.

Comment: @e-ba'e Okay, I've edited the question to be more clear about what you're asking. There are two things to know, however: 1) That means the answer you've accepted doesn't answer your question at all, and 2) You need to include your code in the question, otherwise it will be closed as off-topic. (Questions asking how to do something with existing code are required to include that existing code)

Comment: @TylerH thank you very much. I'll do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a border on the right of the left column (or the left of the right column) like this:

```css
.split-left {
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.split-right {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 split-left">LEFT COLUMN</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 split-right">RIGHT COLUMN</div>
  </div>
  </div
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you read the body text, it has nothing to do with the question in the title.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG despite my vague question, you helped for the first part :)